# Different Property setter for three same class objects in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What I am trying to implement are three different temperature values depending on the city name.
The following class:

```
class City(val name: String) {
    var degrees: Int = 0
    set(value) {
        when(this.name){
            ("Dubai") -> 30
            "Moscow" -> 5
            "Hanoi" -> 20
        }
        field = value
    }}
```

And main func:

```
fun main() {
    val firstCity = City("Dubai")
    val secondCity = City("Moscow")
    val thirdCity = City("Hanoi")
    println(firstCity.degrees) // 0
  }
```

Why is it set to default value 0? For Dubai it should have been 30.

Comment: 1) You don't invoke setter that's why degrees property is not getting updated. 2) result of `when` isn't assigned to anything, so even you invoke the setter `degrees` won't be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `degrees` are initialized with 0 and never changed due to no invocation of the setter, which lacks a value for cities that are not expected (maybe that's why you initialized the `degrees`?).

You could do what you want way shorter:

```kotlin
class City(val name: String) {
    var degrees: Int = when(name) {
                           "Dubai" -> 30
                           "Moscow" -> 5
                           "Hanoi" -> 20
                           else -> 0  // default value for unpredictable cities
                       }
}

fun main() {
    val firstCity = City("Dubai")
    val secondCity = City("Moscow")
    val thirdCity = City("Hanoi")
    println(firstCity.degrees)
}
```

This will output `30`